# Roth's Theorem: number of trivial triangles

Tags: graph-theory

I don't understand how the bound on the minimum number of trivial triangles is established in the proof for Roth's Theorem.

An explanation can be found [for example on this page](http://matheuscmss.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/applications-of-szemeredis-regularity-lemma-triangle-removal-lemma-roths-theorem-corners-theorem-and-graph-removal-lemma/).

We identify arithmetic progressions as triangles in a tripartite graph. I don't get why there are more than $\epsilon n^2$ trivial triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chose $i \in V_1$. We have $n$ possibilities to do this. Later, chose $j \in V_2$ such that $j - i \in A$. We have at least $\varepsilon n$ possibilities. Finally, we have just one possibility to choose $k \in V_3$ such that $k - j = j - i$.